# Extract files from multiple folders in R

Tags: r

I have a directory full of folders [image: Like this], and in each of those folders is a .tsv file I need to extract to a different directory (so that all the files in the folders are together in one folder)

My idea was to write a for loop in R which would get a list with all files in root directory, open those, copy the .tsv file to the new location

it would look something like this:

```
Files <- list.files("directory")
directory1 <- "root directory"
directory2 <- "place they need to go"
for (i in files){
file.copy(from = directory1,
          to = directory2)}
```

this however does not work.

Comment: You are just putting directories/file paths in the `file.copy()` command, not the file names themselves. Your loop has errors because you define `i` but don't use it in the loop at all. You may want to try `..(from = paste0(directory1, i, ....)` in your loop (though make sure there is a / at the end of `directory1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it may be late now, the solution is in specifying the `recursive=` and `full.names=` arguments in the `list.files()` function.

After that you can copy the files without using loops:

```
Files <- list.files("directory", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE) 
file.copy(from=Files, to="new_directory")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `i` in the loop so that's part of the problem. Try

```
for (i in files){
  file.copy(from = file.path(directory1, i),
            to = file.path(directory2, i))
}
```

Comment: This did not work, I think there must be a way to specify the file that has to be moved

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work". Did you get an error? Does the file not appear in the new location? Or did you want to move it rather than copy it? There's also `file.rename` rather than `file.copy` if you want to move the file.

Comment: the file indeed does not appear in the new location. sorry for the uncertainty

Comment: You have both `"directory"` and `"root directory"` in your code. Are these paths the same? If the file doesn't exist, I would expect you to get an error. What does `length(Files)` return. Are you sure there are files in the list?

Comment: no these paths are not the same, lenght files returns 5. this is correct as there are 5 folders with files (in this example)

Comment: If you are listing files in "directory", then that's where the need to be copied from. I don't understand what "root directory" would be. Why are there three different directories involved? It seems like there should be just two. The source directory and the destination directory.